# How can I create an HTTP server in flutter web?

Tags: flutter-web

I've found a lot of ways to create a server in flutter but none of them work in flutter web, only mobile. That's mainly because the dart:io package doesn't work for web and the universal_io hasn't implemented the server class. So how can I create a server?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example with a dart

```
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;

Response _echoRequest(Request request) => Response.ok('Request for "${request.url}"');

void main() async {
  var handler = const Pipeline()
               .addMiddleware(logRequests())
               .addHandler(_echoRequest);

  var server = await shelf_io.serve(handler, 'localhost', 8080);

  // Enable content compression
  server.autoCompress = true;

  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}
```

The package https://pub.dev/packages/shelf